# Show Hide script not working in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a lot of ways to do a show hide in jquery, but I am just wondering why is below not working. I am getting [object Object] as an alert, when trying to debug for

```
alert($("div.$(this).attr('class')"))
```

My Script goes like below:

```
$(".blocks").hide(); 
$("div.$(this).attr('class')").show();
```

Any Ideas, how to fix this, or make sure that  `alert($("div.$(this).attr('class')"))` returns class name instead of object object.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings:

```
$("div." + $(this).attr('class')).show();
```

or:

```
$("div." + this.className).show();
```

Note that `alert()` returns `[Object object]` for objects, use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The way you have it, `$(this).attr('class')` is literally what it says. It's just a string.

You need to concatenate it:

```
$("div." + $(this).attr('class')).show();
```

Comment: but I was getting alert an object and not any string, So cant we nest div, e-g though the script works but I am getting object as an alert here too $(this).parent().next().find($(this).attr("class")); WHY?

Comment: Because `$(this)` is an object and `'$(this)'` is the string `'$(this)'`. Strings are just strings.

Comment: I think I didn't ask it properly, how would I get the below to return className and not object.  $(this).parent().next().find($(this).attr("class"))

Comment: `$(this).parent().next().find($(this).attr("class")).attr('class')`

Comment: Now it alerts me undefined

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest `$(this)` inside your selector like that.

```
$("div." + $(this).attr('class')).show();
```

Comment: Do you know why cant we nest element with $this?

Comment: It is because the jQuery selector you are using expects a string (among other choices: dom element, jQuery object, etc). There is no notion of $(this) inside of the string. It will only be parsed as a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different...

```
$("div." + this.className).show();
```

If you didn't have jQuery...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div." + className), function(element) {
     element.style.display = "";
});
```

If you were trapped in old browser land...

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0, len = div.length; i < div; i++) {
    if (div[i].className == className) {
         div[i].style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Setting `display` property to an empty string makes it use its default value for that element.

Comment: You rock, but can you throw some light on second script, I mean forEach.call

Comment: @Mike `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array, but a `NodeList`, so you can't call `forEach()` on it. Instead, we directly call `forEach()`, and pass the returned `NodeList` as its context.